# Java UTF-8 Encoding/decoding is only displaying the first word

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, utf-8, aes

i have a quick question that will hopefully be a quick fix.

I currently have a client/server program which takes input from the client, encodes this using UTF-8 into a byte Array, Encrypts the Array using AES, send it to the server, and reverses the process for decryption.

The only issue is, if the message has a space from the user, it will only display the word before the first space as the decrypted message.

E.G:

> Input: Hello i am Tom
>
> Output: Hello
>
> But if my Input is all one word, it decrypts perfectly
>
> Input: HelloIamTom
>
> Output: HelloIamTom

I cannot find information on this anywhere!

Any help would be appreciated,

**CLIENT CODE**

```
 System.out.println("Please type a message to be encrypted:");
       message = scanner.next();


     //create iv array
     byte[] iv = toByteArray("a11f001ed2dec0de6e6f6e73656e7365");

     Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
     SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKey, "AES");
     IvParameterSpec ivParSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
     aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParSpec);
     byte[] encryptedMessage = aesCipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));


     dos.writeInt(encryptedMessage.length);
     dos.write(encryptedMessage);
```

**SERVER CODE**

```
  int length = dis.readInt();//recieve length of byte array for incoming message
        byte[] encryptedMessage = new byte[length];//create a byte array to the length recieved
        dis.readFully(encryptedMessage);//fill the byte array with incoming data

        //decrypt using AES

        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");//create a cipher with correct parameters
        IvParameterSpec ivParaSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);//create IvParameter spec using IV provided in assignment brief

        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key,ivParaSpec);//initialise the Cipher in DECRYPT mode
        byte[] decryptedMessage = aesCipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage);//create decryptedMessage and put in byte array

        String decMess = new String(decryptedMessage,"UTF-8");

        System.out.println("User ID:");
        System.out.println(uid);

        System.out.println("Decrypted Message:");
        System.out.println(decMess);
```

Comment: Instead of `message = scanner.next();` try... `message = scanner.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2):

See [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

and [Scanner#next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of `hasNext()` returned `true`.

If you want to scan the hole line, your modified client code is:

```
System.out.println("Please type a message to be encrypted:");
message = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `message = scanner.next();`. Instead of this you should be doing `message = scanner.nextLine();` to take the complete line as input.